# Obtener años y meses con Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy intentando crear 2 fechas, 1 con la que pide el usuario por html y la otra se crea en el día de hoy, la finalidad es saber si la fecha que crea el usuario en el html es menor o igual que la existente, es decir, existe Diciembre 2019 y enero 2020, pero NO existe febrero 2020.

```
 public checkDisabledMonth(month) {
        let dateUser = new Date(parseInt(this.selectedYear, 10), month, 1);
        let dateCurrent = new Date();
        console.log('dateUser', dateUser);
        console.log('dateCurrent', dateCurrent);
        if (dateCurrent.getFullYear >= dateUser.getFullYear) {
            if (dateCurrent.getMonth >= dateUser.getMonth) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Básicamente el problema que tengo que al usar new Date() para crear las fechas, cuando hago el .getFullYear o .getMonth me sale una "f" y un código de una función por la consola de html, pero yo no quiero eso, yo quiero obtener los años para poder compararlos.

Edit: Al usar . con Date sólo me da 2 opciones el VisualStudio: getFullYear o getUTCFullYear , no me sale la opción de getYear como veo por google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dateCurrent.getMonth` y `dateUser.getMonth` son funciones. Si quieres invocar esas funciones tienes que usar paréntesis:

```
dateCurrent.getMonth()
dateUser.getMonth()
```

De esa manera se puede evaluar la función y devolver el resultado a las expresión que estás tratando de implementar:

```
if (dateCurrent.getMonth() >= dateUser.getMonth())
```

Pasa lo mismo con `dateCurrent.getFullYear` y `dateUser.getFullYear`